# How to resolve dll versioning in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

I am using asp.net web application.

I have one product where it dll named as opensp.dll. This application used the latest version of this app and it is 6.0.

There some class library modules which are used the reference of opensp.dll and it is older and it is 4.0. When I individual built these class library with 4.0 it is successfully built ,but it not allowed with the 6.0. No worries for not to built in 6.0.

but my problem is these class library's built dlls path to asp.net application(opensp.dll)'s bin directory. so when I run this web application it gives me error of some method not found of opensp.dll. so I have replace new version of opensp.dll 6.0, then every this works fine. my application and modules of class libraries.

So each time when I built dll of class library I have put copy of opensp.dll to bin . I made back up of opensp.dll somewhere else. I don't have code of opensp.dll.
Can you please suggest to overcome this copy paste and work smooth process?

Answer (score 0):

check your

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("X.0.0.0")]
```

in assemblyinfo.cs of class library . Is it still 4.0.0.0 ? Also your question is a bit unclear so let me ask , are you planning on keeping both dlls ? If yes have a look at side-by-side execution of assebmlies :- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8477k21c(v=vs.110).aspx

You can strongly name both the assemblies and deploy in GAC , but it not recommended to do so as the GAC is a shared resource and is available to all the applications running in the framework .

Comment: Is it possible to omit uses of GAC and configured only this for a single application? means only to the currently running application.?

Comment: did you check assemblyversion in assemblyinfo.cs ? what is the assembly version value there ?